# Bulk insert vs Single insert

Tags: elasticsearch, bulkinsert

The primary dev managing our ES cluster has made the statement that single document loads to ES will only provide us with roughly 30 / 40 creations a second.  Whereas the bulk operations will give us more in the range of a 1,000+. I realize that bulk is always faster (or is generally) and there are hardware / environment constraints to any process.  However, with other technologies you do not pay such a heavy price for single insertions.  I am obviously ignorant when it comes to ES.  Why do you pay such a heavy price for document writes in ES? Or are we just not properly informed?

Environment:

- Apache Storm writes to our ES cluster
- Currently all of the writes are processed in bulk operations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have to take into account is the round trip time between your loader and your cluster.  Setting up an http connection, transferring the data, and then waiting for a response can take a while -- in this case it seems it's taking your about 30 ms.  Elasticsearch has to setup a parser for your request, hand it off to the node that is really going to do the work, and then generate the response back to you.

By using the bulk API, you remove a lot of back and forth -- ES can group together inserts going to the same node, doesn't have to instantiate a new parser for every request, etc.

HTTP Connection pooling for single requests would help, but doing bulk inserts/updates/deletes is always going to be faster in the long run.

Comment: Thanks @Alcanzar that makes sense.  I am new to ES so I appreciate the feedback.

Comment: Hi @scarpacci, I have made some works on storm and ES. Maybe that could help you. [storm-trident-elasticsearch](https://github.com/fhussonnois/storm-trident-elasticsearch).

Answer (score 1):

Bulk indexing is indeed way faster but it is not as bad as you system admin suggests. Elasticsearch has gotten a lot better at this stuff over the past two years.

We're able to do hundreds of inserts/updates per second without bulking requests. Most inserts take around 1 ms (including sending the http request and receiving the response). If insert speed becomes an issue, you can back off on the cluster refresh (default 1s). Also, you can use multiple threads to insert. Bulk insert can get in the range of 10000s, depending on how complex your mappings are.

You definitely want http connection pooling (true when using any kind of webservice in anger) or even better, run an embedded elasticsearch node. Another alternative is to run an elasticsearch node on localhost if you don't want to do an embedded node. That way, all http traffic is on localhost.

Finally, if you need to support more concurrent writes, you can always increase the number of shards and nodes. These numbers are not set in stone. If you need tens of thousands of writes per second, it should be possible to engineer a cluster that can do it. It will require a lot of tuning and hardware probably, and you should probably not do this unless you have a really good reason to do so. However, the whole point of elastic search is horizontal scalability.

Comment: "when using any kind of webservice in anger" - is the last word a typo for "general"?